# How to make a button disable automatically?

Tags: javascript, button

I'm trying to code a button - each time you click it, it disables for 3 seconds...but for some reason, it waits a second then disables it. How would you make it so that it disables automatically? This is some of my code so far:

```
function countdown() {

    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('btnOne').disabled = null;
    }, 4000);

    var countdownNum = 4
    incTimer();

    function incTimer() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (countdownNum != 1) {
                countdownNum--;
                document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = 'Click again in ' + countdownNum;
                incTimer();
                document.getElementById('btnOne').disabled = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = '';
                document.getElementById('btnOne').disabled = false;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it waits exactly 1 second, it might be related to your `setTimeout(...,1000)` inside `incTimer()`

Comment: The code is wrapped in a timeout that waits one second, so why would it execute any sooner ?

Comment: @adeneo Maybe post that in answer form...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
<span id="timeLeft"></span>
<input type="submit" id="btnOne" onClick="countdown()">


function countdown() {
    document.getElementById('btnOne').disabled = true;

    var countdownNum = 3
    document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML  = 'Click again in ' + countdownNum;
    incTimer();

    function incTimer() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (countdownNum != 1) {
                countdownNum--;
                document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = 'Click again in ' + countdownNum;
                incTimer();
                document.getElementById('btnOne').disabled = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = '';
                document.getElementById('btnOne').disabled = false;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code does the things you need.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fclick(){
    document.getElementById('myButton').disabled = true;
    setTimeout('countDown(3);', 1000);
}

function countDown(i){
    if (i >= 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('myButton').value = 'Click again in ' + i + ' secs';
        i--;
        setTimeout('countDown('+i+');', 1000);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('myButton').value = 'Click me';
        document.getElementById('myButton').disabled = false;
    }
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click me" id="myButton" onclick="fclick()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a `timeout` that says "after 1 second, do X".
Your current timeout is actually pretty hard to follow, but it broadly does this in a very tangled way:

1. Make `counter` = 4
2. Wait 1 second.
3. If `counter != 1`, subtract 1 from the counter, disable button, and go back to **2**. Continue otherwise.
4. Enable button.

As you can see, you are disabling the button AFTER waiting 1 second, not immediately.

I would suggest changing your countdown() method as follows:

1. Disable button.
2. Make `counter` = 3
3. If `counter > 0`, Print "Click again in `counter` seconds", Subtract 1 from `counter`, *Wait 1 second* and go back to **2**. Continue Otherwise.
4. Enable button.

That could look like this: (using your code)
**[--- Working Example Here!!! ---](http://codepen.io/Goodwine/pen/ChFxp)**

```
function countdown() {
    document.getElementById('btnOne').disabled = true;
    //3 is more understandable than 4 for your example.
    var countdownNum = 3;

    incTimer();

    function incTimer() {
        if (countdownNum > 0) {
          // Order of statements IS important.
          // Note the differences in this IF block.
          document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = 'Click again in ' + countdownNum;
          countdownNum--;
          setTimeout(function(){
            // Note that the whole timeout was moved inside,
            // Imagine this is recursive function, with a delay.
            incTimer();
          }, 1000);
        } else {
          document.getElementById('timeLeft').innerHTML = '';
          document.getElementById('btnOne').disabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

There are better ways to express your code, but I tried to stick as much as possible to your code style.